# Javascript function results

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn javascript and programming overall. I found these examples and trying to figure out results of those two functions.

First:

```js
(function(){
  var x = y = 11; 
})();  
console.log("x = " + (typeof x !== 'undefined')); 
console.log("y = " + (typeof y !== 'undefined'));
```

Results are true and false. 
Is it because var x is declared with var keyword so it is local var and y is not?

and second example:

```js
(function(){
  console.log("a");
  setTimeout(function(){console.log("x")}, 1000);      
  setTimeout(function(){console.log("y")}, 0);      
  console.log("b"); 
})();
```

Please explain me the second example?
If I got it right, setTimeout will wait for execution even if time  is set to 0.

Thanks

Comment: What don't you understand in the second example?

Comment: You answered your first question yourself. What is to be explained in the second example? I don't see any strange result. Plus, why you ask two distinct, unrelated questions in a single post?

Comment: What is algorithm here? what you dont understand in the second example,please be clear about it

Comment: In first I just wanted to be sure that I got it right.
And in second why is executed in that order? why first, console logs then timeout functions?

Comment: For the first question, you're basically assigning the same value to different variables

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) for second example.

Comment: Please review [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Correct. If you'd remove the 'var' from the 'x'-declaration that variable would also be available outside the function scope.

Second: The javascript function 'setTimeout' starts an asynchronous operation. In other words, the passed function gets added at the end of the queue to be operated at a later time, even if the passed time is 0ms.
The 'console.log' functions run synchronously, so they always will be executed before the functions given with the 'setTimeout'-function.